# how to get return value from server after POSTing from a html form

Tags: javascript, html, post

I have a form :

```
<FORM name="loginForm" ACTION="https://www.example.com/cgi-bin/login.pl" METHOD="post">
```

The form submits a username and password to my perl script on the server which verifies the password is correct. However since my page login.html is a static page is it possible to have the Post return the value to me somehow in a javascript that will display to the user an error message if the password did not match for example, without having to go to a different page.

This can obviously be done by the server, serving a new page, but that's not what im looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to post the form contents from JavaScript.

If you're using jQuery, there is an example on the [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) page:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize()); // Assumes form id is "testform"
```

See the bottom example on the page ("Example: Post a form using ajax and put results in a div") to get more complete code for how to get the return value form the server.

Answer (score 0):

There're many solutions for your problem. A simple one is in case of login failure let your login.pl returns an html containing a "redirect to login.html" element and with parameters indicating the error, the html looks like:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1; URL=login.html">
```

Your login.html should contains logic (in Javascript) to check parameter for error and display it.